# Raspberry Pi Audio File Read blocks in Simulink for multiple audio files

Tags: simulink

I am using multiple Raspberry Pi  Audio File Read blocks in Simulink so I can play back, randomly (full file and not partial playback) and from the beginning, any of the audio files. My issue is, how can I individually play/select each audio file, programmatically?

Thanks

[Audio File Read](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/ref/audiofileread.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each Audio File read block into separate 'Enabled subsystem'.

Enable each subsystem programmatically to play/select the required audio file

Comment: Fantastic! I knew it was something simple. I swear I tried that before...I must have tried a function block and not the Enabled subsystem. Thanks!!!